# Manage Focus on stateless Components - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Having a container Component which hold state. it renders a number of stateless components.

I want to get access to all of their DOM nodes, so i can call the [focus method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on demand.

I am trying the `ref` approach as it is [encouraged by the react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).

I'm getting the following error: 
`Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.`

What is the recommended way to get around this error?
preferably, without extra dom elements wrappers like exra divs.
Here is my Current Code:

**Container Component** - responsible for rendering the stateless components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StatelessComponent from './components/stateless-component.jsx'

class Container extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.focusOnFirst = this.focusOnFirst.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            words: [
                'hello',
                'goodbye',
                'see ya'
            ]
        }
    }
    focusOnFirst() {
        this.node1.focus()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.words.map((word,index)=>{
                        return <StatelessComponent
                        value={word}
                        ref={node => this[`node${index}`] = node}/>
                    })
                }
                <button onClick={this.focusOnFirst}>Focus on First Stateless Component</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Stateless Component** - for sake of simplicity, just display a text inside a div.

```
import React from 'react';
export default function StatelessComponent(props)  {
    return <div>props.value</div>
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stateless (functional) components can't expose refs directly. However, if their internal components can use refs, you can pass a function from the parent (the grandparent) of the stateless component (the parent) as a ref via [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html). Use the function as the ref target of the DOM element. Now the grandparent has direct access to the DOM element ref.

See [Exposing DOM Refs to Parent Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) in React's documentation.

```js
const StatelessComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div>
    <input ref={ref} {...props} />
  </div>
));

class Container extends React.Component { 
  itemRefs = []

  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusOnFirst();
  }

  focusOnFirst = () => this.itemRefs[0].focus()

  inputRef = (ref) => this.itemRefs.push(ref)

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StatelessComponent ref={this.inputRef} />
        <StatelessComponent ref={this.inputRef} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Container />,
  demo
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: As of 16.3 you can use `React.forwardRef` if you wanted to update/append it to your answer: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936#issuecomment-377731659

Comment: Good idea. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, basically you pass a callback as ref to the stateless components that gets the input instance an adds it to an array owned by the container

```
class Container extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this._inputs = [];
        this.focusOnFirst = this.focusOnFirst.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            words: [
                'hello',
                'goodbye',
                'see ya'
            ]
        }
    }
    focusOnFirst() {
        this._inputs[0].focus()
    }

    refCallback(ref) {
        this._inputs.push(ref)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.words.map((word,index)=>{
                        return <StatelessComponent
                        value={word}
                        refCallback={this.refCallback}/>
                    })
                }
                <button onClick={this.focusOnFirst}>Focus on First Stateless Component</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And the stateless get modified a little too

```
function StatelessComponent({refCallback, value})  {
    return <input ref={refCallback} value={value}/>
}
```

[Here's a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3WYyKG?p=preview)